# 検証ツールのinspector-stylesheetを、変更するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPressでサイトを作成しています。素人です。

検証ツールで変えたいところを見ると、要素のスタイルに
ファイル名がinspector-stylesheetと記入されています。

そこはphpで表示した抜粋文の部分ですが、
この文字の大きさを変えようとしています。

これはどうしたら可能になるのでしょうか？

functions.php

```
    function twpp_change_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 70; 
  }
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twpp_change_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

archive.php

```
        <div class="blog-item-excerpt">
    <?php echo mb_substr( get_the_excerpt(), 0, 50 ) . '[...]'; ?>
        </div>
                <?php // 抜粋を表示させる end ?>
```

で呼び出しています。

Answer (score -1):

下記にある程度の説明がありました。
https://willcloud.jp/knowhow/dev-tools-01/
２つ日後になってもう一度やってみたところ、何故か普通にできるようになりました、
明確なやり方は分かりませんが、ご協力してくださった皆様、ありがとうございました。